# Copying one folder to a new location

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file with another folder in the same parent folder. I want to copy that folder to a new location by doing this:

```
set src = "testing"
set dest = "%APPDATA%\test"
xcopy %src% %dest% /-y
```

```
[parent folder]
　├─testing
　│　└─files1...
　└─bat.bat
```

However this doesn't work, any idea why?

PS: It says `Invalid number of parameters`.

Comment: Do you have write permission for the destination?  Can you successfully copy a single *file*, rather than a *directory*?

Comment: @BobGilmore - I tried changing the destination to desktop and also tried copying just a single file, but it is still not working.

Comment: @BobGilmore - I found out the problem is that I added spaces around the `=` in `set`...